# Where does Javascript random get its entropy from?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, entropy

Where does Javascript random get its entropy from?

I don't need cryptographically secure random data, but I do need to know collision probabilities in my particular use cases, e.g. two browsers running on the same machine, or two tabs in the same browser.

For example, PHP session id's [use(d) IP address as an entropy source](https://youtu.be/fWk_rMQiDGc?t=485), which greatly increses collision rate if used on the same machine by reducing the entropy by 32 bits, making the key space 2^32 times smaller. They also used the time since unix epoch, which is almost constant when generating many values in a row, removing another 32 bits.

Comment: [Here's an article on the topic about V8 in particular.](http://v8project.blogspot.com/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html) Generally you should probably assume that there's no source of entropy other than the inherent properties of the PRNG algorithm chosen.

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined by [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-math.random). So you'll need to look at the source code of the JavaScript engines used by the browsers in question, as engine vendors are free to make their own decisions on this. (Of course, this assumes an open source engine like [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8) in Chrome or [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code) in Firefox; Microsoft may not be keen on your looking at the JScript source used in IE; the core of [Chakra](https://github.com/microsoft/ChakraCore), used in Edge, appears to be open-source.) (And of course, they're free to change that decision over time.)